# PySpark - Format String using Column Values

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to create a new column that creates a string using 4 columns.

```
df.withColumn("input",
                    F.lit("http://address.com/process?field1={}&field2={}&field3={}&field4={}".format(F.col('field1'),F.col('field2'),F.col('field3'),F.col('field4'))).show()
```

However, where I'm trying to insert the column values into the string, it's showing up as `field1=Column<'field1'>` instead of the actual value. I tried wraping it in `F.format_string` as well but I'm not getting the actual values.

So what it should be returning is something like this, assuming that each column has a `string = VALUE`.

```
http://address.com/process?field1=VALUE&field2=VALUE&field3=VALUE&field4=VALUE
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`format_string`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#format_string) function like this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = df.withColumn(
    "input",
    F.format_string(
        "http://address.com/process?field1=%s&field2=%s&field3=%s&field4=%s",
        F.col('field1'), F.col('field2'), F.col('field3'), F.col('field4')
    )
)

df.show(truncate=False)

#+------+------+------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
#|field1|field2|field3|field4|input                                                         |
#+------+------+------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
#|a     |b     |c     |d     |http://address.com/process?field1=a&field2=b&field3=c&field4=d|
#+------+------+------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: This is clean, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`concat`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.concat), not `lit`, so something like `F.concat(F.lit('http://example.com/'), F.col('field1'), F.lit('/'), F.col('field2'))`